# Как удалить обьект из обьекта масивов и сохранить поля?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такого вида обьект:
Нужно удалить (filter , delete без разницы) обьект в зависимости от переменной currentDate и вернуть newArr

```
const currentDate = 'month'
```

```
const newArr = {
      month: [
        { count: 1, price: 10, _id: '63239a84e7c9298231788ce6' },
        { count: 2, price: 20, _id: '63239a84e7c929345tqgr46' },
      ],
      year: [{}],
      weak: [{}],
      day: [{}],
}
```

*Делаем какие-то действия и получаем обьект такого вида*

```
const newArr = {
      month: [
        { count: 1, price: 10, _id: '63239a84e7c9298231788ce6' }
      ],
      year: [{}],
      weak: [{}],
      day: [{}],
}
```

Comment: из того что вы приложили вообще непонятно как `currentDate` сравнивать с тем, что лежит в `newArr.month`...можно увидеть какой-то рабочий пример, чтобы не теряться в догадках о том как их сравнивать?

Comment: @МихаилРебров ну например по price . Например что типо этого newArr[currentDate].filter((dateItem) => dateItem.price !== price)